# Node Fetch blobFromSync and blobFrom TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to read a file that is local to my computer into a blob using the node-fetch library, but each time I do, I get this Invalid Url Error. My code is the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const fetch = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));

const blobFromSync = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ blobFromSync }) => fetch(...args));

  const blobFrom = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ blobFrom }) => fetch(...args));

  const fileFrom = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ fileFrom }) => fetch(...args));



const app = express();
const port = 3000;

//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
    next()
});


app.get('/recorded', async (req, res) => {

    try {
   
        let file_location = './path/to/video.mp4';

        const file = fileFrom(file_location);

        const chunkSize = 40000

        for (let start = 0; start < file.size; start += chunkSize) {
            const chunk = file.slice(start, start + chunkSize + 1)
            //Will eventuay doa fetch
            //await fetch(url, { method: 'post', body: chunk, headers: headers, }).then(res => res.text())
        }

        res.status(200);
        res.send().end();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

The error is the following (its also uncatchable):

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:377:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:563:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:643:5)
    at new Request (file:///Users/xxxxxx/Development/terminal-backend/node_modules/node-fetch/src/request.js:55:16)
    at file:///Users/xxxx/Development/terminal-backend/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:51:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (file:///Users/xxxx/Development/terminal-backend/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:49:9)
    at /Users/xxxxx/Development/terminal-backend/src/server.js:11:53 {
  input: './path/to/video.mp4',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
}
```

blobFromSync and blobFrom also throw the same error. If this is a local file, why am I get invalid url?

Comment: the way you import node-fetch is probably the most *interesting* I've seen ... of course, when you use your `fileFrom` function it simply calls `fetch`, it never calls `fileFrom` that you *imported*

Comment: @JaromandaX The node-fetch has issues with the regular import unless ur inside a module

Comment: Indeed - my point is, shouldn't you be doing `const fileFrom = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ fileFrom }) => fileFrom(...args));` - otherwise, you're importing `fileFrom` but executing `fetch` instead ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with the how you're importing the functions other than fetch

i.e.
const fileFrom = (...args) =>
import('node-fetch').then(({ fileFrom }) => fetch(...args));

Imports `fileFrom` but uses `fetch`

Simplest fix is as follows

```
const fetch = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));

const blobFromSync = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ blobFromSync }) => blobFromSync(...args));

const blobFrom = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ blobFrom }) => blobFrom(...args));

const fileFrom = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ fileFrom }) => fileFrom(...args));
```